# String comparison hanging in IntelliJ for large strings

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock

We have some Spock tests that compare XML as strings. This mostly works fine, but for one test where the strings have ~130k characters, IntelliJ's test runner seems to hang. The terminal's output shows the status of the test, but the left-hand pane with the tests just spins forever. For now we're breaking the strings up into 1000-character chunks and comparing those, but is there anything we can do to get IntelliJ to complete the test when run?

Comment: This is specific to intellij?  So all is fine when running the tests e.g. from your build tool?

Comment: Have you debugged into the comparison to see what is actually going on while it "just spins forever"?  It isn't clear what is happening during the spin cycle.

Comment: The string comparison fails, but in a typical amount of time. The strings are indeed identical, however.

Comment: "The string comparison fails, but in a typical amount of time. " - What is it that is spinning forever?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown when I debug, once execution gets back to Gradle classes, I see this message: `Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.gradle.internal.dispatch.MethodInvocation.toString()`

However, once I step through all the stack, the test is still spinning in IntelliJ.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sorry, my previous comment about the typical amount of time was responding to cfrick's question.

Comment: I have seen many cases in which unit or integration tests have long finished, but somehow IntelliJ IDEA does not notice and shows some tests as unfinished, even though their results were printed to the console already (if they print anything). I never detected any specific pattern for when this happens, but it is mostly an ugly GUI glitch and does not mean that the tests really hang or anything becomes unresponsive in the GUI. If it is the same for you and you have a reproducible test case, please file an IDEA bug.

Comment: Please file an issue in the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA attaching a code sample to reproduce the case to it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using something like xmlunit? My guess is that intellj chokes on the large error output that they have to parse from the socket connection.

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, but now a direct comparison is working just fine.